# Multiple panels appear when restart or log-in

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, gnome-panel

When I log-in or restart a gnome session all of the items in my panels are duplicated. I get an additional 'Applications' and 'Places' menus, additional screens buttons and additional top and bottom panels.

I have tried Alt + right clicking but this is only a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem after installing Cinnamon, Gnome-shell, & KDE environments. Uninstalling the desktops does not fix either. Here is a screenshot.[image]